# Recorrer mayor número de casillas en un laberinto

Tags: algoritmos, busqueda, lenguaje-agnóstico

Esta pregunta no está relacionada con ningún lenguaje de programación.

Quería consultar sobre si **existe algún algoritmo** que te permita recorrer un número **lo más cercano al 100% de casillas** dentro de un laberinto. Con casillas dentro de un laberinto me refiero a un laberinto formado por casillas (cada una con su coordenada *x* e *y*) de una altura y anchura determinada (en la imagen que adjunto es un 20x20).

Adjunto una imagen del laberinto a resolver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los ratones comenzarían en la casilla **0x0** tomándose como la **esquina inferior izquierda** e irían recorriendo el laberinto intentando pasar por el mayor número de casillas diferentes posible.

Tengo conocimiento de algoritmos como **A*** que te permite llegar de un punto *A* a un punto *B* en el menor recorrido posible, pero para un trabajo de la universidad necesito (implementado todo esto en **Java**) que un ratón recorra el mayor número de casillas posible dentro de un laberinto.

Hasta el momento, encontré un método llamado ***método de la mano derecha*** el cual te permite encontrar una posible salida y lo he implementado con éxito en **Java**, pero no se me ha podido ocurrir ninguna forma de garantizar que me recorra todo el laberinto o la mayor parte de este.

Comment: No se lo que es una casilla de un laberinto, ¿puedes añadir su explicación a la pregunta?  Aunque no tenga que ver con ningun lenguage de programacion procura hacer un [example] aunque sea con pseudocodigo

Comment: Lo he actualizado por si está más claro ahora. Gracias!

Comment: He agregado la etiqueta **Java** a tu pregunta pues dices que lo estas haciendo en Java, así acotamos un poco la pregunta (no creo que varie el número de respuestas que puedan darte por eso, pero quizás algunas ya esten más orientadas a lo que necesitas)

Comment: Okay, gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Sugiero más bien utilizar la etiqueta `[lenguaje-agnóstico]` en lugar de `[java]`, ya que justamente se menciona que la pregunta _no está relacionada a ningún lenguaje de programación_.

Comment: @padaleiana Hecho!  Aunque al principio dice eso luego sí que hablaba de java, y como lo estaba usando para su trabajo de la universidad me ha parecido correcto ponerlo, pero tampoco conocia esta otra etiqueta. Total, te he hecho caso, confio en tu criterio :-)

Comment: Se puede pasar por el mismo lugar dos veces? Si eso es así, el laberinto debería poderse representar como un grafo y puedes usar DFS o BFS para recorrerlo

Comment: Si no es así, el problema se reduce a encontrar el camino más largo en un grafo. Lo cual es un problema NP-Hard, y probablemente lo mejor que puedas hacer es enumerar todos los caminos y tomar el más largo.